# does varchar column contain an optional range of keywords

Tags: sql, sql-server, search, range, optional-parameters

I have the following query in which I select where a varchar column contains any one of up to five, optional keywords passed into the stored proc.

```
@keyword1 varchar(100) = null
@keyword2 varchar(100) = null
@keyword3 varchar(100) = null
@keyword4 varchar(100) = null
@keyword5 varchar(100) = null

SELECT supplier_code 

FROM crm_cache

WHERE  (@keyword1 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%'))
    OR (@keyword2 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword2 + '%'))
    OR (@keyword3 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword3 + '%'))
    OR (@keyword4 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword4 + '%'))
    OR (@keyword5 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword5 + '%'))
```

It works and returns correctly when all five keywords have been passed and are not empty, but if I supply keywords 1 and 2, leaving 3,4 and 5 to default to null. The returned data is massive and incorrect.

If I remove the null clause and set keywords 1 and 2 like below, I get the correct data which is three rows

```
@keyword1 varchar(100) = 'ruby'
@keyword2 varchar(100) = 'silver cross'
@keyword3 varchar(100) = null

SELECT supplier_code 

FROM crm_cache

WHERE  (@keyword1 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%'))
    OR (@keyword2 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword2 + '%'))
```

but with a clause which has a null variable like keyword 3, I get hundreds of rows returned

How should I implement a query like this which has optional parameters to compare against one column?

Should I use Contains instead of LIKE?

Can you see where my logic is wrong in the conditions?

Answer (score 4):

Your logic is correct, but not quite what you want.  If you were using `AND`, then it would be fine:

```
WHERE (@keyword1 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%')) AND
      (@keyword2 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword2 + '%')) AND
      (@keyword3 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword3 + '%')) AND
      (@keyword4 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword4 + '%')) AND
      (@keyword5 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword5 + '%'))
```

But that is not what you want.  I think you can just leave out the `NULL` comparisons:

```
WHERE (crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%')) OR
      (crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword2 + '%')) OR
      (crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword3 + '%')) OR
      (crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword4 + '%')) OR
      (crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword5 + '%'))
```

When one of the keywords is `NULL`, then the clauses return `NULL` (which is treated as not-true).  However, if any are true, then the `OR` will return true.  This is the logic you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
@keyword1 IS NULL OR crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%')
```

- if the `@keyword1` is NULL, the whole condition will be true regardless of other checks since it's all `OR`s. Same for all other variables.

You need this:

```
@keyword1 IS NOT NULL AND crm_cache.search_string LIKE ('%' + @keyword1 + '%')
```

...for each variable, combined together with `OR` like it is now. But the logic needs to be that at least one of the parameters is not null and matches the input.